# How to change Eclipse indentation style for automatically generated code?

Tags: eclipse, coding-style, indentation

Is there any way to change indentation style for automatically generated code in Eclipse?
I'd like to change from

```
class Test {
blah blah
}
```

to

```
  class Test 
  {
  blah blah
  }
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

If you do change the format of the brace, all new class will be generated according to that new format:

[image: brace option]

Comment: Thanks a lot! A spent ages looking for that.

Answer (score 2):

It's in "Window | Preferences" in the latest eclipse.

Comment: ... as indicated in the accepted answer, given two years earlier. *Everything* is in Window > Preferences anyway in Eclipse.